# Webpack - Specify dependencies to include or exclude

Tags: npm, webpack

I have a project which has both a web front end and an API back end.  The front-end dependencies are compiled with Webpack.  In development mode, I use webpack-dev-server on port 9000 and the front end is served on port 3000.  In production mode, the back end server serves both the API and the html, css, and js files which Webpack produces on the same port from the same server.

Some dependencies are for the back end only, but Webpack is including them in my application's bundle.js file, which is making the bundle much larger than it needs to be.

Is there any way to tell Webpack "some dependencies are not to be bundled"?